# show all not empty tables in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a simple PostgreSQL or even SQL way of listing empty/not empty tables?

P.S.:
I'm analyzing a database containing hundreds of tables and would like to detect "death code".
I assume, when the table after some month is still empty, than it's not used.

**EDIT:Solved**

Thank you all! 
Finally this statement seems to output the statistics I can use:

```
select schemaname, relname, n_tup_ins from pg_stat_all_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' ORDER BY n_tup_ins
```

Comment: you want to see unused table by specific date or empty tables?

Comment: And what happens if all rows of a table was removed for a valid reason? Like having tasks and all tasks are successfully completed and then removed from table. What if you drop the table and someone tries to create a new task?

Comment: @user1474602: empty tables, those which have never been write-accessed.

Comment: @LajosArpad: I have not sait, I will remove the tables. Just to know which to watch

Comment: Yeah, get information from *pg_stat_all_tables* seems to be a good method:


PostgreSQL's statistics collector is a subsystem that supports collection and reporting of information about server activity. Presently, the collector can count accesses to tables and indexes in both disk-block and individual-row terms. **It also tracks the total number of rows in each table**, and information about vacuum and analyze actions for each table...

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking for the number of rows *could* give you wrong results. Assume that a table is used as a staging table: rows get inserted (e.g. from a flat file), processed and deleted. If you check the number of rows in that table you could very well believe it's never used if you don't happen to run your query while the processing takes place.

Another way to detect "unused" tables would be to monitor the IO and changes that are done to the tables.

The statistic view [pg_stat_user_tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) records changes (deletes, inserts, updates) to each table in the system. The statistic view [pg_statio_user_tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STATIO-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) records IO done against the tables.

If you take snapshots of those tables in regular intervals you can calculate the difference in the values and see if a tables is used at all.

You can use `pg_stat_reset()` to reset all values to zero and then start from that.

Answer (score 11):

You could use PostgreSQL's system catalogs with e.g.

```
SELECT n.nspname, c.relname
FROM pg_class c
INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON (n.oid = c.relnamespace)
WHERE c.reltuples = 0 AND c.relkind = 'r';
```

According to the documentation, the number of rows is an estimate, though.

If your tables have columns that take their default values from sequences, you could list them and check their values with `nextval`. (Unfortunately, `currval` returns a session-dependent value, so you'd have to ensure that no one else is using the database and use both `nextval` and `setval`.)

```
SELECT n.nspname, c.relname
FROM pg_class c
INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON (n.oid = c.relnamespace)
WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
```

(Unfortunately I couldn't yet find any way to determine, which sequence belongs to which table. Obviously it would be very helpful. Anyway, you can use `pg_class.relnamespace` to narrow down the results.)

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/catalogs-overview.html for details.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_table()
  RETURNS TABLE(name text,count int) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    data record;
    v_sql text;
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE demo (name text,count int);
    FOR data in (SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public')    LOOP
        v_sql := 'INSERT INTO demo SELECT '''||data.table_name||''', COUNT(*) FROM '||data.table_name;
        RAISE INFO 'v_sql:%',v_sql;
        EXECUTE v_sql;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN QUERY (SELECT * FROM demo);
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

OUTPUT :

```
"child";0
"location_master";6
"location";5
"tmp";5
"a1";7
"b1";3
"master";0
"child2";0
"child1";0
```

Here child, master , child1 , child2 has 0 count that means they are empty tables.

Comment: Thanks. Bu unfortunately no rows found. I've just realized, that I did a very stupid thing. Run your query which contains create/drop on production database. I hope I have not destroyed anything.

Comment: No, This create TEMP table and also delete the same. Nothing else so no need to worry

Comment: No COUNT(*) needed if you are just showing empty tables: 
https://gist.github.com/tallpeak/bd6b3b3fbb979c478378f7bb3290e22c

Answer (score -2):

Please try this once,hope it helps you:

```
Running the query below will give you a list of tables and indexes that have not been used since SQL Server was last restarted. Once you have a list of tables, you can do a dependency check to get a list of stored procedures that use each table. Then you can search your C# source code for thos SPs and table names.



-- Unused tables & indexes. Tables have index_id’s of either 0 = Heap table or 1 = Clustered Index

SELECT OBJECTNAME = OBJECT_NAME(I.OBJECT_ID), INDEXNAME = I.NAME, I.INDEX_ID

FROM SYS.INDEXES AS I

INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS AS O

ON I.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID

WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(O.OBJECT_ID,'IsUserTable') = 1

AND I.INDEX_ID

NOT IN (SELECT S.INDEX_ID

FROM SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS AS S

WHERE S.OBJECT_ID = I.OBJECT_ID

AND I.INDEX_ID = S.INDEX_ID

AND DATABASE_ID = DB_ID(db_name()))

ORDER BY OBJECTNAME, I.INDEX_ID, INDEXNAME ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Unfortunately I get "ERROR:  schema "sys" does not exist"

Comment: need to refine the code little bit i think so,i have used this thats why posted the same.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz i have checked this it is working perfectly.Please check once at your end i.e for other databases too

Comment: That query is not valid for Postgres (looks like a SQL Server/T-SQL query)

Comment: It's a "SQL ***Server***" query. `SQL` is just a query language it is **NOT** a DBMS product. The tag `sql-server` is used for SQL Server specific queries. The tag `sql` only refers to SQL as a query language in general.